# Subtleties on comprehension sets

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic

I see that a typical definition of the cartesian product $A \times B$ is $\{ x \in \wp\wp A \cup B: \exists a \exists b (a \in A \wedge b \in B \wedge x=(a,b)) \}$. I have come up with an alternative that does not use the quantifiers and I don't think is entirely equivalent, logically speaking, to the traditional one and I don't know if it would be correct.

$\{ x \in \wp\wp A \cup B: x=(a,b) \leftrightarrow (a \in A \wedge b \in B) \}$

Is there a difference between the two? In the same way, I am thinking that the best way to define the inverse of a function $f:A \rightarrow B$ would be

$\{ z \in B \times A: z=(y,x) \leftrightarrow y=f(x) \}$

Comment: Are you quantifying existentially or universally? Is it "for all $a,b$, $x=(a,b)$ if and only if $a\in A$ and $b\in B$" (and if so, over what universe are $a$ and $b$ taken?), or is it "there exists $a$ and $b$ for which $x=(a,b)$ if and only if $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ (and again, what is the universe of discourse for $a$ and $b$?)

Comment: Your expression works out to $\{(a,b)\}$ if $a\in A$ and $b\in B,$ otherwise $\wp\wp A\cup B\setminus\{(a,b)\}$ (as Arturo says, you need to quantify $a$ and $b$ somehow. Otherwise they'd be parameters, like $A$ and $B$ are, which surely isn't what's intended.)

Comment: Say we are quantifying universally; take $A=\{1\}$ and $B=\{2\}$. Then taking $a=2$ and $b=1$, we have that for $x=\varnothing\in \mathscr{PP}(A\cup B)$, we have $x\neq(2,1)$, and also $2\notin A$ and $1\notin B$, so "$2\in A\wedge 1\in B$" is also false. Thus, the biconditional is satisfied, so $\varnothing$ is an element of your set.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin - yes, you convinced me. But if I quantify universally x and y, I suppose then my definition of the inverse function would work? As $B \times A$ does not contain the empty set, I guess I'd be safe?